# How to generate new war without replacing old war for each build in Jenkins?

Tags: grails, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Grails version 1.3.7
Jenkins version 1.625.1
I have created Grails Build in Jenkins for grails project available in SVN path.
The configuration that i made in Jenkins job is given in picture,Config_snap.jpg  [jenkins grails config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pflIF.jpg)

SampleProject-01.war is getting generated in target folder of Jenkins job workspace.
When i create a new build, the previous war is getting replaced by new war.
How to generate new war for each build in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible just remove the option "Discard Old Builds"